# When page is scrolled, fix div to its bottom when it reaches its end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 parallel divs, when page is scrolled and a specific div reaches its end I need to stop it from scrolling but continue scrolling for the other div.

Comment: Harikumar where is your code, we are here to sort out the problems not giving you the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

try using this plugin of Jquery for both of your div.
[scrollbox-jquery plugin](https://github.com/Invis1ble/scrollbox)